# finding the max/min sum in js... why does this fail?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
  // Write your code here
  let max = Math.max(...arr);
  let min = Math.min(...arr);
  let minsum = 0;
  let maxsum = 0;
  for (let x in arr) {
    if (arr[x] != max) {
      minsum += arr[x];
    };
    if (arr[x] != min) {
      maxsum += arr[x];
    }
  };
  console.log(minsum, maxsum);
}
```

I got this from hackerrank, and apparently it fails certain test cases but I have to pay 5 "hackos" to learn why

Comment: Please share how you are using `miniMaxSum`? Please also share what test cases it fails?

Comment: Are you meant to be _returning_ something from the function rather than just logging something? It should also be `const let x of arr`. `in` is for objects.

Comment: What is it supposed to do? Your `minsum` is not the sum of minimum values, it's the sum of everything except the maximum.

Comment: Your code fails for the input `[5, 5, 5, 5, 5]`.

Comment: Start with `arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);` Next you can do `const minsum = arr.slice(0, 4).reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr);` and `const maxsum = arr.slice(1, 5).reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr);`

Comment: I believe this code is supposed to find the smallest sum of four out of five values and the largest sum of four out of five values. So if you exclude the maximum value (but only once) and add up the rest you should have the `minsum`.

Answer (score 1):

my simple code

```
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
    var max = 0;
    var min = 0;
    arr.sort();
    for(var i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(i>0 ){
            max = max + arr[i];
        }
        if(i<4){
            min = min + arr[i];
        }
    }
    console.log(min + " " + max);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 let n = prompt('Enter your number:');
let number = [];
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    number.push(Number(prompt('Enter #' + i + 'number:')));
}
let sum = 0;
const max = Math.max.apply(null, number);
const min = Math.min.apply(null, number);
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    sum += number[i]
}
let average = sum / n;
console.log(`max is ${max}`);
console.log(`min is ${min}`);
console.log(`average is ${average}`);
```

Comment: You haven't explained anything.

Answer (score 0):

Are all the integers supposed to be unique? If not then this may not work if there are duplicates of max and min numbers?

For example [2,2,3,5,5]

Answer (score 0):

So, I just got the problem to understand what it is supposed to do. What you need to do is to find the 4 biggest values in an array of integers and sum it, and also need to find the 4 smallest values and sum it. (hackerrank link: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/mini-max-sum/problem)

I'll let the code down below with comments so you can understand

```
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
    //make a copy of the original array to calculate the max sum value
    let arrMax = [...arr];
    //make a copy of the original array to calculate the min sum value
    let arrMin = [...arr];
    let maxSum = 0;
    let minSum = 0;

    // We need to find the sum of the biggest/lowest 4 values
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        //find the index of the element with the biggest value
        let maxElementIndex = arrMax.findIndex(value => value === Math.max(...arrMax));
        //sum the value to the max sum result
        maxSum += arrMax[maxElementIndex];
        //remove the value from the array
        arrMax.splice(maxElementIndex,1);

        // here I am doing the same, but now to get the lowest value
        let minElementIndex = arrMin.findIndex(value => value === Math.min(...arrMin));
        minSum += arrMin[minElementIndex];
        arrMin.splice(minElementIndex,1);
    }
    console.log(`${minSum} ${maxSum}`);
}
```

Now, some tips for you before you create a new question.

1. create with the max of details, for example, you could explain better the problem before sending the code.
2. Try to explain what you understood for the problem and what your are trying to do. I believe you just misunderstood what the problem was asking.

I hope I could help you. You can leave any comment if something is difficult to understand and I will try to help you. And happy coding! :)